# How to loop from a particular index of an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am using a nested loop, and I want my inner loop to start from the index of the outer loop.

How can I implement this?

I want `j` to run from `i` till the end of the array.

```
nums = [2,7,11,15]

for i in nums:
    for j in nums:
        print(j)
```

Comment: If `j` starts from `i` then you will get an IndexOutofBounds exception as soon as 2nd iteration when `i` becomes 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it solve your problem?

```
nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]

for i in range(len(nums)):
    for j in range(i, len(nums)):
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = [2,7,11,15]

for i, val in enumerate(nums):
    for j in nums[i:]:
        print(j)
```

This output is interested for you?

2
7
11
15
7
11
15
11
15
15

Answer (score 0):

If there is no duplicates in your array, you can do

```py
for i in nums:
    for j in nums[nums.index(i):]:
         print(j)
```

else a more generic way is

```py
for i in range(len(nums)):
    for j in nums[i:]:
         print(j)
```

Comment: [Claude Shannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Shannon) would never offer the first solution.